# Было реализовано тысячи проектов или были реализованы тысячи проектов?

Tags: согласование, глаголы

«В течение своей работы нами было (были) реализовано(ы) тысячи масштабных проектов».

Как правильно? И каким правилом руководствоваться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь только во множественном числе: ***В течение (своей) работы нами были реализованы тысячи масштабных проектов***

Слово "своей" я убрал, оно здесь избыточно, но если автор считает, что без него не обойтись по контексту, - его право.

Если указано конкретное число этих "тысяч", то возможно (и часто даже предпочтительно) согласование в единственном:

***В течение работы нами было реализовано две тысячи масштабных проектов***.

Вот насчет "правила" - сложнее... Просто нет оснований для согласования в единственном, случай не подпадает под оговоренные правила, когда это возможно.
Вообще, как уже сказал, согласование количественно-именного подлежащего со сказуемым возможно как в единственном, так и во множественном числе. Там есть несколько правил, регулирующих выбор варианта, я ограничусь ссылкой. Вот [тут](http://journal.pushkin.institute/archive/archive/1977/77-06/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC.pdf) очень подробно разобраны все случаи, когда один из вариантов предпочтителен.

Но дело в том, что слово "тысячи" здесь выступает как обычное существительное, не являясь количественным числительным. Следовательно, и оснований для  применения всех этих правил нет.

Comment: @slava1947 спасибо! Спасли от конфуза.

Answer (score 1):

Интуиция мне подсказывает, что правильно будет так:
Приблизительное количество, обозначаемое числительным с указанием направления предполагаемого отклонения (больше / меньше):
… нами было реализовано более (или свыше, или не менее, или около) тысячи масштабных проектов
Неопределенное количество, обозначаемое обобщающим словом (ср., м., ж. рода, а так же словом во мн.числе, которым может оказаться имя числ.):
… нами было реализовано множество (море, несметное число) масштабных проектов
… нами была реализована масса (куча, туча, уйма) масштабных проектов
… нами был реализован пул (заранее очерченный круг) масштабных проектов
*… нами были реализованы тысячи (считанные единицы из всех запланированных) масштабных проектов
Точное количество проектов:
… нами были реализованы (семь тысяч сто сорок два, или три, или) четыре проекта
… нами были реализованы (сто одна тысяча сто сорок пять, или шесть, или семь, или восемь, или) девять проектов
Если речь идет о точном значении с окончанием на один / одна / одно, то:
… нами был реализован (пять тысяч сто сорок) один проект
… нами была реализована (пять тысяч сто сорок) одна новация
… нами было реализовано (пять тысяч сто сорок) одно начинание

Значком * отмечен ответ на вопрос. Остальные примеры даны для сравнения.

Comment: У вас очень много "интуиции", а между тем все случаи, когда есть каие-то сомнения давно разобраны. Всего более непонятно, при чем тут мужской или средний род, упоминаемый под "звездочкой". И вообще, в теории, у Розенталя, говорится не о "приблизительном количестве", а о разделении случаем числительного и счетного существительного (сотня, десяток, тройка и проч.), куда можно отнести и "тысячу" в том значении, которое здесь использовано).  Чего огород-то городить?

Comment: За замечание спасибо. Только понять его мне не дано, особенно про соседство "звездочки" и среднего рода.